# how i can grab value and node as string using simplexml in php

Tags: php, xml

Example, I have an xml code like this:

```
$xml=<<<XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cars>
  <desc1>
       <h1>Title 1</h1>
       <p>Content</p>
  </desc1>
  <desc2>
       <h1>Title 1</h1>
       <p>Content</p>
  </desc2> 
</cars>
XML;
```

How can I grab string between tag `<desc1>...</desc1>` using simplexml so the output like this:

```
$output='<h1>Title 1</h1>
           <p>Content</p>';
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DOMDocument` then load that xml into it. Target that `desc1` then get its children, save it and put it inside a container string. Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$output = '';
$desc1 = $dom->getElementsByTagName('desc1')->item(0)->childNodes;
foreach ($desc1 as $children) {
    $output .= $dom->saveHTML($children);
}

echo $output;
```

Comment: thanks for fast replay, but when i execute the code, i got an error like Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given @ghost

Comment: yeah, i got it,..... the problem is in php ver 5.3.5 for property of DOMDocument::saveHTML() doesnt accept param, so i upgrade my php to 5.5.x and its work like charm... DOMDocument::saveHTML($param) introduce at php ver 5.3.6... thx :)

Comment: @mgx oh okay, img glad this helped, you might also want to take a look at ThW's answer as it is also good alternatively to it

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @Ghost you could use Xpath to fetch the child nodes directly.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$output = '';
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//desc1[1]/node()') as $child) {
    $output .= $dom->saveHTML($child);
}

echo $output;
```

The Xpath expression:

Select all `desc1` nodes anywhere in the document: 
`//desc1`

Limit to the first found node: 
`//desc1[1]`

Get the child nodes (including text nodes): 
`//desc1[1]/node()`

Answer (score -1):

Just an alternative for your specific simple example:

```
$output = "";
if(preg_match("/<desc1>[^<]*(<.*>)[^>]*<\/desc1>/s",$xml,$reg)) {
  $output = $reg[1];
}
```